# Postman Test - If/else if clause stuck on 1st IF

Tags: if-statement, postman

I am trying to verify that the language from "accept-language" is taking the correct information (aka correct translations).

since the language in the header is like: en, de, es and the translations fed to the request body are: german, english, spanish, I was thinking of the below, but all the responses are compared to the first if, that's it.

Can someone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
if (responseData = "english") {
    pm.test("Check that the response language is EN, same as the Pre-request one, PASSED", () => {
        pm.expect((pm.environment.get("language"))).to.be.equal("en")
    })
} else if (responseData = "german") {
    pm.test("Check that the response language is DE, same as the Pre-request one, PASSED", () => {
        pm.expect((pm.environment.get("language"))).to.be.equal("de")
    })
} else if (responseData = "spanish") {
    pm.test("Check that the response language is ES, same as the Pre-request one, PASSED", () => {
        pm.expect((pm.environment.get("language"))).to.be.equal("es")
    })
} else if (responseData = "portuguese") {
    pm.test("Check that the response language is PT, same as the Pre-request one, PASSED", () => {
        pm.expect((pm.environment.get("language"))).to.be.equal("pt")
    })
} else if (responseData = "islandic") {
    pm.test("Check that the response language is IS, same as the Pre-request one, PASSED", () => {
        pm.expect((pm.environment.get("language"))).to.be.equal("is")
    })
}
```

Comment: please add sample response and clarify what is the problem? I don't understand

Comment: `=` is an assignment and will always return a truthy. Use `==` or even better `===` for comparison

Comment: Where & how is `responseData` set?